# SQL Server Conversion error numeric to varchar : One server return an error and other server does not return an error

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, vmware

I have a stored procedure which has an

> invalid conversion error numeric to varchar.

This wasn't give any error message despite having the same issue in the stored procedure. However after the server's VM host failure on yesterday, same stored procedure gave a conversion error. Then I restored the backup in a different SQL server and SP does not give any error despite having the conversion error.

1. How this behave differently in two servers?
2. Is there a possibility to automatically change the SQL server's default settings after the VMWARE host failure ?

Your's comments are highly appreciated on this

Answer (score 0):

You can use Transaction Management in your store procedure to manage your transaction code and control it with TRY block. When occur error it will Rollback transaction and rise error to you

```
BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRANSACTION
    SQL Statement.....;
  COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
     Catach statement....;
END CATCH
```